# Micronaut server and httpclient behind corporate proxy

Tags: http-proxy, micronaut

I'm running a micronaut microservice on a Win 7.

My GET Request looks like : **http://localhost:8080/maps/myreq**.

The controller use a httpclient to send request to an external webseite : **image.maps.api.here.com**

When running without proxy, all went fine and the response is ok (an image).

But when running behind the proxy, connection timed out. Proxy works fine for any other applications or browser.

How to set micronaut server behind proxy to properly root requests?

***edit*** : when sending a request, the netty server respond with an error : **unable to connect to image.maps.api.here.com:xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx** where xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx is the proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set micronaut server behind proxy to properly root requests?

You can set the `https.proxyHost`, `https.proxyPort`, `http.proxyUser` and `http.proxyPassword` system properties.  A common place to do that is in the `MN_OPTS` environment variable.  For example, you could set `MN_OPTS` to have a value like `"-Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.proxyUser=test -Dhttp.proxyPassword=test"`.

See https://docs.micronaut.io/1.1.0/guide/index.html#proxy for more info.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thx. But I'm on Windows and the documentation with "Environment Variables" is a bit unfinished. It is the same if i want to use the system proxy settings?

Comment: I am not sure what is unfinished but if you set those system properties in the `MN_OPTS` environment variable, I expect Micronaut to find and use them.

Comment: As the docs say... `"For Windows systems the environment variable can be configured under My Computer/Advanced/Environment Variables"`.

Comment: system variables with name: MN_OPTS with value: -Dhttps.proxyHost=xx.xx.xx.xx -Dhttps.proxyPort=xxxx doesnt help and user variables with name: https.proxyHost with value: xx.xx.xx.xx and another with name: https.proxyport with value=xxxx neither.

Comment: They appear to work here.  If they don't' work for you please file a bug report at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues and we can investigate.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: They all work here too (Windows10). Make sure you type the proper address! in my case, the IT team told me the proxy host address in the compnay is http://193.120.2.1 but you should just use the IP address "-Dhttps.proxyHost=193.120.2.1 "

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with settings the proxy for the CLI but also by setting the proxy in the application.yml like here :
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1611